# Function by group returning NAs

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have the following data frame that I am trying to make a function for:

```
df<- structure(list(BLG = c(37.037037037037, 12.0603015075377, 93.5593220338983, 
3.96563119629874, 77.634011090573, 71.608040201005, 3.96563119629874, 
119.775421085465, 44.8765893792072), GSF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 11.090573012939, 
0, 0, 0, 0), LMB = c(66.6666666666667, 24.1206030150754, 40.6779661016949, 
31.7250495703899, 73.9371534195933, 67.8391959798995, 31.7250495703899, 
22.4578914535246, 31.413612565445), YLB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 14.7874306839187, 
0, 0, 0, 0), BLC = c(3.7037037037037, 0, 4.06779661016949, 7.93126239259749, 
7.39371534195933, 11.3065326633166, 7.93126239259749, 3.74298190892077, 
22.4382946896036), WHC = c(7.40740740740741, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
7.48596381784155, 4.48765893792072), RSF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 4.48765893792072), CCF = c(3.7037037037037, 0, 8.13559322033898, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BLB = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), group = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

**Function**

```
p_true<- c(83, 10, 47, 8, 9, 6, 12, 5, 8) #true value for each column 

estimate2 = function(df) {
  
  y_est2 = df
  
  sqrt(mean((y_est2-p_true)^2))/p_true*100
}


final<- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify(~ as.data.frame.list(estimate2(.)))
```

The final output should be a 3x9 data frame: one value for each column per group. Can get the intended output format with `plyr::ddply(df, .(group), estimate2)`

Even without trying to run the function across groups with `estimate2(df)` (and taking out the group column) it still says argument is not logical or numeric; returning NA.

I'm not sure why though because I've run functions very similar to this one that only differ slightly by the actual equation inside and they work fine.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: A 3x9 dataframe. One value per column, per group

Comment: I can also get the intended output format with plyr::ddply(df, .(group), estimate2), but all of the values are NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `mean` command. Looking at the help for it with `?mean` it says:

> x
> An R object. Currently there are methods for **numeric/logical vectors** and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors are allowed for trim = 0, only.

But you want to calculate the mean for three rows of a data frame.

I'm not entirely sure if the following is what you want, but you can unlist your data frame so that it is a vector. The division by `p_true` is then recycled to the length of this vector. You can then combine the result again into a data frame:

```
p_true<- c(83, 10, 47, 8, 9, 6, 12, 5, 8) #true value for each column 

estimate2 = function(df) {
  
  y_est2 = df
  
  return_df <- as.data.frame(t(sqrt(mean(unlist((y_est2-p_true)^2)))/p_true*100))
  names(return_df) <- names(y_est2)
  return(return_df)
}

final<- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify(~ as.data.frame.list(estimate2(.)))
```

This returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Groups:   group [3]
  group   BLG   GSF   LMB   YLB   BLC   WHC   RSF   CCF   BLB
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  38.7  321.  68.3  401.  357.  535.  268.  642.  401.
2     2  45.9  381.  81.1  477.  424.  635.  318.  763.  477.
3     3  45.6  378.  80.4  473.  420.  630.  315.  756.  473.
```

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at this when I get out of class, but at first glance that looks like exactly what I need. Thanks so much for your response!